# Internet Explorer 10 (Windows 8) crashing Apache

Tags: apache, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I just installed Windows 8, and I'm having a hard time running Apache on it.

After a couple of adjustments on httpd.conf file (changing ports because of WWAHost.exe and allowing ::1 due to IPv6) I finally got it running (installed with EasyPHP), but when I open some local site on Internet Explorer 10, Apache stops responding and keep trying to load the page forever.

I think it has to do with Internet Explorer 10, because on other browsers work fine before loading any local site on Internet Explorer. After that I have to restart Apache to work again and not use Internet Explorer 10 any more in order to keep it running.

Did you have the same problem?

Comment: Hello Renan, welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some more information to your post so the others can help you. Does it crash while serving PHP pages or HTML pages? Any code of the sample page that makes this happen? Do you have Windows on a physical machine or a VM? Is it a release version of Win 8 or some platform preview etc?

Comment: You can try to install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to observe the request & response headers and bodies, maybe this will give some debugging hints. You can also look at the request headers and try to reconstruct the same HTTP query via some tool like cURL and observe the behavior.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with Apache 2.4 on Windows 7. When I request a page with Internet Explorer 11, it works the first time but after that Apache hangs and I have to restart it. It works fine in Chrome as long as I don't use IE. As soon as I visit the page with IE, Apache hangs and Chrome does not work anymore either.

Comment: Forgot to mention (don't know if it's important): I am running Apache's httpd.exe directly from the command line. No Services involved. The problem is reproducable for me, it happens for every 2nd request I make.

Comment: Just installed the 2.4 version and was really surprized Apache hangs on IE requests even for static files. More surprized this issue is 3 years old!...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had a similar problem and managed to fix it with the following solution. See *[IE freezes when requesting an EasyPHP/Apache hosted page](http://astutelogic.com/ie-freezes-easyphp-apache/)*.

As I already had a modern Apache, I just added:

```
AcceptFilter https none
AcceptFilter http none
EnableSendfile Off
EnableMMAP off
```

before loadmodules section. This worked like a charm.

My configuration was: Apache 2.4.4 and Internet Explorer 10

Comment: This fixed it for me. I just needed the first two lines though. I wrote [a blog post](http://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2014/01/10/apache-hangs-ie11/) with more info/references.

Comment: The AcceptFilter directive, relevant to the http/https procotol in use, is the main issue here. I can confirm that the first two lines fixed the problem on at least 5 PCs I work with.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running Apache 2.4.2 (EasyPHP 12) with Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7, although think I've found a solution [on astutelogic.com](http://astutelogic.com/ie-freezes-easyphp-apache/) that seems to work... At least, upgrading Apache to 2.4.4 using those instructions worked for me.

I downloaded the Apache binaries from Apache Lounge, then after the extracting/renaming steps, I copied my current 'php.ini' and 'httpd.conf' files across to the new folder and added the additional lines to my 'httpd.conf' file as instructed.

As per the linked page, a note on development servers vs live servers:

> As far as I can see, the AcceptFilter directive only really works on FreeBSD and Linux (to a lesser extent) so there isn’t any benefit from having them on Windows. I could be wrong though… In any case, its only a development environment so a few milliseconds slower shouldn’t be a problem.

**Update**

Just noticed EasyPHP 13.1 has been released, which comes with Apache 2.4.4. If you haven't already tried the steps I linked to above (or simply updated EasyPHP), I'd recommend you just download the updated stack.

Comment: This answer was useful for me in another way....  The source site has Apache 2.4.4, which can also be installed in WAMP server.  WAMP 2.2 comes with Apache 2.4.2 and it ran very slowly.  Once I installed Apache 2.4.4 it ran just about as fast as localhost usually runs.  You guys should also exclude Windows Defender from real-time scanning httpd.exe and mysqld.exe to speed things up as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have been attempting to fix the same issue on Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7 and have found that using compatibility mode alleviated most of the delays using `localhost` sites.

I know it isn't exactly a solution, but I also experienced these issues on Windows 8 and tried the common fixes to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It might be something with ThreadsPerChild.

Check `error.log` and `httpf.conf`:

```
# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
```

I had the same problem in Internet Explorer 10, but now I can't seem to reproduce it. Normally I use Firefox, and there is no problem. It seems I got this problem after updating to Apache 2.4.